# ¿se puede hacer tablas de multiplicar sin ciclos o bucles?

Tags: condiciones, bucles

es una idea tonta pero en mi universidad un prefesor nos puso un reto de escribir la tabla de multiplicar de un numero hasta el 200 solo usando if

Comment: Tu pregunta, al menos para mi, no es clara. ¿Que tendrían que ver los *if* en una tabla de multiplicar?

Comment: Hola BRYAN, bienvenido, teinvito a hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!, también puedes ver [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. Deberías ser más claro para que te podamos ayudar, y agregar lo que has intentado.

Comment: Quizá está pregunta te pueda ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/q/72367691/13419694

Comment: Usando recursividad, tal vez

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una solución implementado JavaScript, sin embargo el concepto es el mismo para cualquier lenguaje

```javascript
let i = 0;
function multiplicar(num){
   console.log(`${num} * ${i} = ${num*i}`);
   i++;
   if (i <= 200) {
      multiplicar(num);
   }
}

multiplicar(2)
```

La función multiplicar aquí es una función recursiva, por qué se llama a ella misma y utiliza el condicional para detener su ejecución.